# Iterator stops midway through after finding a match

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap

```
//Example from class that I was trying to base off of:

public void printMajors(String major) {
for(Student x : dir) {

//dir = new HashMap<Integer, Student>(); and Student is the second class.

if (x.getMajor().equals(major)) {
System.out.println(x.getName());
    }
}
```

}

I want to print out all of the people that have the same area code that is inserted but the iterator stops midway through once it finds a match. How do I have it continue through the loop and print out every person with the same area code?

//Problem in Code

```
public boolean printAreaCode(String areacode) {
    for (String p : phonebook.values()) {
        if (p.startsWith(areacode)) {
            for (String name : phonebook.keySet()) {
                String key = name;
                System.out.println(key);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Whole Assignment

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class PhoneBook {

    private HashMap<String, String> phonebook;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    PhoneBook phone = new PhoneBook();
    phone.addEntry("Alexander Schnell", "987-654-3210");
    phone.addEntry("Bob the Builder", "555-555-5555");
    phone.addEntry("Michael", "465-858-5555");
    phone.addEntry("Robert", "778-555-1234");
    phone.addEntry("Charlie", "987-546-4564");
    phone.addEntry("Steve", "909-555-7845");
    System.out.println("All of the people in the directory:");
    phone.printListings(); //works
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("People with matching area codes:"); //WIP
    phone.printAreaCode("987");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Prints phone number for requested person:");
    phone.getNumber("Bob the Builder"); //works
}
//Adds a new entry to the phone book (naturally).
//It has two parameters, both Strings: the person’s name and their phone
//number (in the form “610-499-4035”).

public void addEntry(String name, String number) {
    phonebook.put(name, number);
}
//prints the names and phone numbers of everyone in the phone book

private void printListings() {
    for (Iterator<String> it = phonebook.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        for (String p : phonebook.values()) {
            String key = (String) it.next();
            System.out.println(key + ": " + p.toString());
        }
    }
}
//looks up a number in the map.
//It has one parameter (a person’s name) and returns a PhoneNumber object.

public String getNumber(String name) {
    //public void getNumber(String name) {
    // no return statement
    System.out.println(phonebook.get(name));
    return phonebook.get(name);
}
//prints the names of all people with the given area code

public boolean printAreaCode(String areacode) {
    for (String p : phonebook.values()) {
        if (p.startsWith(areacode)) {
            for (String name : phonebook.keySet()) {
                String key = name;
                System.out.println(key);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
    }

    public PhoneBook() {
        phonebook = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }
}
```

I don't even think this class communicates with my main class.
My teacher just said that it had to be included.
This could possibly be an issue.

```
public class PhoneNumber {
    private String areacode;
    private String prefix;
    private String four;

    //Insert a phone number
    public PhoneNumber(String number) {
        String[] parts = number.split("-");
        areacode = parts[0];
        prefix = parts[1];
        four = parts[2];
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = areacode + "-" + prefix + "-" + four;
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do yo think `return true;` is doing?

Comment: It's keeping the println from printing out all of the names. I can't remember if it would print it once or twice all the way through. Either way, the return true; statement keeps it from doing that.

Comment: @MadProgrammer - forgot to tag you.

Comment: Use a local variable as a flag (ie `found`), set it to `false`, as you iterate through you list, each time you find a match, print out the result and set the flag to `true`.  At the end of the method return the flag

Comment: If I do that the program just prints out the list of people twice. @MadProgrammer

Comment: public boolean printAreaCode(String areacode) {
        boolean result = false;
        for (String p : phonebook.values()) {
            if (p.startsWith(areacode)) {
                for (String name : phonebook.keySet()) {
                    String key = name;
                    System.out.println(key);
                    result = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

Answer (score 1):

**You're iterating through your Map wrong** Your `return true;` statement is the cause of your issue, but we'll ignore that for the moment.

Always iterate through maps like this:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry: phoneBook.entrySet())
{
    if(entry.getValue().startsWith(areaCode))
    {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use entry that would require me to import something. I can't import anything else. @jdb1015

Comment: It's not that the way the OP is iterating over the `Map` is "wrong", it's just inefficient, perhaps you should take the time to explain "why" your method is better, otherwise it's just you saying "do this" with no real evidence/reason why anybody should trust you - It's an opportunity to educate ;) - *"but we'll ignore that for the moment"* - so, you've not actually answered the question then?

Comment: @Minnyme56 Why not?  `Entry` is an inner class of `Map`, so technically, you're not really importing anything new and as jdb has demonstrated, you don't need to include any imports, you can access the inner class through `Map.Entry`

Comment: I tried for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry: phoneBook.entrySet())
{ and it told me to import java.util.Map; @MadProgrammer

Comment: @Minnyme56, that's kind of ridiculous, but if you _absolutely have to_ you can write `java.util.Map.Entry<String, String>` and you won't have to do any extra imports.  But that's the most ridiculous restriction I can imagine.

Answer (score 1):

So, you need to print the `key` of the `value` which `startsWith` `areaCode`, so your code is basically a little backwards.

Currently you code scans for the values looking for a match, which is okay, but then it prints all the `key` values?

Instead, you need to start with each `key`, get the `value` and then test to see if that `value`, associated with the key, matches the `areacode`, for example

```
public boolean printAreaCode(String areacode) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (String key : phonebook.keySet()) {
        String value = phonebook.get(key);
        if (value.startsWith(areacode)) {
            System.out.println(key);
            found = true;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Now, this is incredibly inefficient. As basically, for each iteration, you're asking the `Map` to go find a value associated with the `key`, this requires the `Map` to search through all it's various entries/nodes, trying to find the matching key.  While in your example, it's probably not a massive delay, it really should be avoid where ever possible.

Instead, `Map` provides access to the `Entry`, which pair the `key` and `value` into a single object, making it's access much faster, for example...

```
public boolean printAreaCode(String areacode) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : phonebook.entrySet()) {
        String value = entry.getValue();
        if (value.startsWith(areacode)) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            System.out.println(key);
            found = true;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Now, `HashMap` is an implementation of `Map`, so normally, I prefer to use

```
private Map<String, String> phonebook;
```

instead of

```
private HashMap<String, String> phonebook;
```

unless I have a particular need for some functionality only defined in `HashMap`, this way, may code won't care if I use a `TreeMap` later on

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN'T ADD THIS LINE?! `import java.util.Map;`

I'm curious as to why you can't add an `import` statement; is that part of the criteria or do you not know how?

You have to essentially iterate through your map twice. And yes, this is highly **inefficient** code.

```
public boolean printAreaCode(String areacode) {
boolean haveMatch = false;
for (String p : phonebook.values()) {
    if (p.startsWith(areacode)) {
        String value = p;
        for (String name : phonebook.keySet()) {
            if(value.equals(phonebook.get(name)) {
                System.out.println(key);
                haveMatch = true;
        }
    }
}
return haveMatch;
```

}

Comment: The only import statement I'm allowed to have is java.util.HashMap; My instructor made an exception with the Iterator since we learned how to use it but he said that any other import wouldn't be necessary. He also said that most of the methods should only have 1 line of code (2 max) so that's why I'm feeling like something is wrong. @jdb1015

Comment: Unless he's giving you a coding riddle, `entrySet()` is always more efficient. Show him my first answer and see what he says. I'm curious if he's trying to be tricky or doesn't know Java very well himself!

Comment: Since he said most methods, I figured that could mean that this one would be the one that is not among the "most" that he was talking about.

Comment: We haven't learned entrySet() yet. I don't think we will be looking at that until next semester since we already are starting to move into inheritance.

Comment: Ask him him about `entrySet()`. Curious to know if he's aware of it....which would be disconcerting if he isn't and is teaching some sort of Java class.

Comment: I'm positive that he knows it very well. The fact that I've gotten this far so quickly is impressive for me. Usually I wouldn't be at this point in coding until next month.

Comment: He mentioned it but said that we won't be looking at it while we work on the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your intent is to just print the phone numbers where the are code begin with a certain value. So we don't have to return anything from the method , You can make the return type as void. You can make it similar to your `printListings`

```
public void printAreaCode(String areacode) {
    for (String p : phonebook.values()) {
        if (p.startsWith(areacode)) {
            for (String name : phonebook.keySet()) {
                String key = name;
                System.out.println(key);

            }
        }
    }

    }
```